# SAX: if schema takes a list of XSD, which one will it use?

Tags: java, xml, xsd, sax

I have difficulty understanding `newSchema(Source[] schemas)` of class `SchemaFactory`.

I want to know that, if each schema of **Source[]** has a unique **namespace**, and when we use the `saxParser` from the factory to parse a XML that doesn't have any namespace, which XSD will it take to validate the XML ?

Thanks.